# Extension Download error public extensions directory

Tags: extension

Hi this message has started appearing on our CIVI CRM system over the last couple of days - it is intermittent and not there all of the time. Any advice on this would be much appreciated. Thank you Helen.

EXTENSION DOWNLOAD ERROR
The CiviCRM public extensions directory at [https://civicrm.org/extdir/ver=5.41.1|cms=Drupal](https://civicrm.org/extdir/ver=5.41.1%7Ccms=Drupal) could not be contacted - please check your webserver can make external HTTP requests or contact CiviCRM team on CiviCRM forum.

Comment: What version are you using - may be relevant

Answer (score 0):

There is a folder in to which extensions can be downloaded to be used on your site. Some server administrators, us included, prefer to not have any folder 'publically available' for security reasons.

The downsides for the site user is they cannot just grab another extension to try out. The upside is we do not have part of our system potentially vulnerable.

I am not sure if this is the issue you are describing. If you go to civicrm/a/#/status on your site, do you have an error like

> Read-Only Extensions: Your extensions directory (//civicrm/extensions) is read-only. If you would like to perform downloads or upgrades, then change the file permissions.

Comment: It's more likely the letsencrypt certificate issue. See multiple issues in chat.

Comment: for example https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/pl/km6ody1jitymzgwsbo4dse8ifh

Comment: or https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/pl/q6gcugnkmtb8igc5cyr3n5sdoh

Comment: I think you should post as an answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Pete for looking up those chat links. I think this is probably the LetsEncrypt issue that's been coming up since Oct 1. https://letsencrypt.org/docs/dst-root-ca-x3-expiration-september-2021/

You likely need to update something on the server. Unfortunately exactly what needs updating seems to vary based on the hosting and several factors.